# All .cpp files depend on two .h files?

Tags: makefile, nmake

In a makefile, I have the following line:

```
helper.cpp: dtds.h
```

Which ensures that helper.cpp is rebuilt whenever dtds.h is changed. However, I want ALL files in the project to be rebuilt if either of two other header files change, kind like this:

```
*.cpp: h1.h h2.h
```

Obviously that won't work, but I don't know the right way to get nmake to do what I want. Can someone help? I don't want to have to manually specify that each individual file depends on h1.h and h2.h.

Thanks. (I'm using nmake included with visual studio 2005.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help, Christoph. I tried:

```
.cpp.obj: h1.h h2.h
```

And got the helpful error message:

```
makefile(58) : fatal error U1086: inference rule cannot have dependents
```

I ended up solving it by making a list of the files that I wanted to compile, and then adding the dependency to the whole list.

```
files = file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj
$(files): h1.h h2.h
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
%.cpp : h1.h h2.h
```

That works in GNU make - no idea if nmake is compatible...

**Edit:** And btw: shouldn't that be

```
helper.o : dtds.h

%.o :  h1.h h2.h
```

After all, you don't want to remake the `.cpp` file (how do you make a source file?), but recompile...

**Edit2:** Check the [NMAKE Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(VS.80).aspx). According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6bt6xe7(VS.80).aspx), something like

```
.cpp.obj: h1.h h2.h
```

might work...

Comment: %.o doesn't seem to work in nmake, unfortunately. And for some reason, both "helper.cpp: dtds.h" and "helper.obj: dtds.h" work fine.